# R Variable Length Differ when build linear model for residuals

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm

I am working on a problem where I want to build a linear model using residuals of two other linear models. I have used UN3 data set to show my problem since its easy put the problem here than using my actual data set.

Here is my R code:

```
head(UN3)
m1.lgFert.purban <- lm(log(Fertility) ~ Purban, data=UN3)
m2.lgPPgdp.purban <- lm(log(PPgdp) ~ Purban,  data=UN3)
m3 <- lm(residuals(m1.lgFert.purban) ~ residuals(m2.lgPPgdp.purban))
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
> m3 <- lm(residuals(m1.lgFert.purban) ~ residuals(m2.lgPPgdp.purban))
Error in model.frame.default(formula = residuals(m1.lgFert.purban) ~ residuals(m2.lgPPgdp.purban),  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'residuals(m2.lgPPgdp.purban)')
```

I am not really understanding the why this error actually take place. If it was log related issue then I should have gotten the error when I am building first two models.

Comment: You are possibly creating logs of negative numbers which are `NaN`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your default `na.action` is most likely `na.omit` (check with `options("na.action")`). This means that `NA` values get removed silently, resulting in different lengths of the residuals vectors. You probably want to use `na.action="na.exclude"`, which pads the residuals with `NA`s.

```
library(alr3)
options("na.action")
#$na.action
#[1] "na.omit"

m1.lgFert.purban <- lm(log(Fertility) ~ Purban, data=UN3,na.action="na.exclude")
m2.lgPPgdp.purban <- lm(log(PPgdp) ~ Purban,  data=UN3,na.action="na.exclude")

m3 <- lm(residuals(m1.lgFert.purban) ~ residuals(m2.lgPPgdp.purban))
#Coefficients:
#                 (Intercept)  residuals(m2.lgPPgdp.purban)  
#                    -0.01245                      -0.18127
```